# Use cookie for alive-check

Tags: haproxy

I running a NodeJS-App behind a HAProxy.
HAProxy performs an alive-check every 2 seconds in my configuration.

Here is my problem:

The nodeJS-App creates a session (via cookie) and saves it to a database. But because the alive-check doesn't pass a cookie the app creates a new session for every alive-check and my database is getting full of unnecessary sessions.

Is there any way to configure HAProxy to send a defended cookie with the alive-check?

Comment: mdunisch, please do not forget about your **[bounty for question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50679264/)**. Please, write me an answer here or under my answer there and I will delete this comment.