# MDCSnackbarFoundation Class usage

Tags: javascript, material-design, material-components, mdc-components, material-components-web

How do I use MDCSnackbarFoundation ? with MDCSnackbar

This documentation is not clear enough to get an idea.
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-snackbar#using-the-foundation-class

This is my code and I need to bind MDCSnackbarFoundation for it.

`logger = new MDCSnackbar($selector[0]);`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you have to have a [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) server. And then you have to install a package `snackbar` for [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) like follows:

```
npm install @material/snackbar
```

**Responding to a Snackbar Action**

To respond to a snackbar action, assign a function to the optional `actionHandler` property in the object that gets passed to the show method. If you choose to set this property, you must *also* set the `actionText` property.

```html
<div class="mdc-snackbar"
     aria-live="assertive"
     aria-atomic="true"
     aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="mdc-snackbar__text"></div>
  <div class="mdc-snackbar__action-wrapper">
    <button type="button" class="mdc-snackbar__action-button"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
import {MDCSnackbar} from '@material/snackbar';
​
const snackbar = new MDCSnackbar(document.querySelector('.mdc-snackbar'));
const dataObj =
{
    message: 'The text message to display.',
    actionText: 'Take action',
    //The function to execute when the action is clicked.
    actionHandler: function()
    {
        console.log('my cool function');
    }
};
​
snackbar.show(dataObj);
```

**For further information:**

- [Design & API Documentation](https://material.io/develop/web/components/snackbars/)
- [Demo Snackbar](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/snackbar)

Before you start with Node.js I would recommend to read one from two books:

- [Learning Node: Moving to the Server-Side](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491943122)
- [Node.js Web Development: Server-side development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1788626850)

Comment: @benvc, would you like to check it befor you think. You can see it in [your example in your comment above](https://plnkr.co/edit/b4v160c186ErrPG5vNza?p=preview) – your example does not work.